# Make A Button Stay At The Bottom Of Its Column, Vertical Align Isn't Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Make A Button Stay At The Bottom Of Its Column**

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have a `.row` with 2 columns in it. Inside both columns there's content followed by a button. Using the `table` `table-cell` approach, the 2 columns match height, and now I simply want the button to stay at the bottom of the row with less content. I'm trying to do so using vertical alignment, but it's not working. *What am I missing?*

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/8z3twkb1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="icon" />
        <h5>Header</h5>
        <p>Yet remarkably appearance get him his projection. Diverted endeavor bed peculiar men the not desirous. Acuteness abilities ask can offending furnished fulfilled.</p>
        <button>Donate</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="icon" />
        <h5>Header</h5>
        <p>Yet remarkably appearance get him his projection.</p>
        <button>Donate</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    display:table
}
.row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
.row > div button {
    vertical-align: bottom; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set that button as absolute position as follows.

```
.row > div:last-child button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**Updated Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8z3twkb1/2/

Comment: One small issue with the absolute positioning. If I chang the width to a relative value, the right button ends up larger than the left. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/8z3twkb1/3/

Comment: @CSSApprentice I have no clue why is that happening, but it works fine on the demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/afvLcnwm/ I doubted it's something related to bootstrap, meanwhile you could use `padding` instead of hard `width` to make the button larger.